# Shopify send email to Admin when click button

Tags: javascript, jquery, shopify

I want to know if there is any shopify API to send email to Admin when the button is clicked.

This is not the contact form.

Just click the button I want to send Admin email with dynamic info on the page.

I can't find shopify API like mail() function in PHP.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think shopify provides such feature for security reasons.
You may want to use third party email services to send emails to your customers

something similar has been discussed [here](https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/shopify-apis-and-technology/t/is-it-possible-to-contact-a-customer-via-the-api-348969) and [here](https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/shopify-apis-and-technology/t/send-email-to-customer-459191) in shopify forum.